# Class member has its own constant member, hence constructor is implicitly deleted

Tags: c++

I have a class and I know why it fails to compile:

```
// My class .hpp
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(/*yet another constructor*/);

private:
    FOO::Dependancy dep_1;
};

// Dependancy.hpp
namespace FOO {
    class Dependancy : public Parent
    {
    public:
        Dependancy(const Bar& _bar);
        ~Dependancy();

        virtual int method_1(/*bla*/);
        virtual int method_1(/*bla bla*/);    

    private:
        const Bar _bar;
    };
}
```

As you see the dependency class has const member. So when compiled, (unlike g++) clang++ tells me exactly what is wrong with the code:

```
1. error: object of type 'MyClass' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
2. copy assignment operator of 'MyClass' is implicitly deleted because field 'dep_1' has a deleted copy assignment operator
3. copy assignment operator of 'Dependancy' is implicitly deleted because field '_bar' has no copy assignment operator
```

My question is, how to solve the issue, knowing that `FOO::Dependancy` and its own members (i.e., `Bar`) and so on, are static libraries which I don't have access to their source code. In other words I can't do anything about that const member and I have to solve the issue within my own class.

Comment: The code you show doesn't have the problem you allege.

Comment: Prefer initialization over assignment, every time. Figure out how class member initialization works.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I literally renamed my variables and posted my compiler output here. This is what I get for calling the constructor of my class by `class_instance = MyClass(/*yet another constructor*/);`. Why do you suggest my code has no problem?

Comment: Your code (the one you've posted here) doesn't contain any function definitions, so it very definitely cannot contain any errors you encounter *when calling those functions*.

Comment: Also, `Parent` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are pretty clear

> object of type 'MyClass' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

So, the copy assignment is implicitly deleted, you have to specify/create one yourself.

The reason why it is deleted is because of `dep_1`, as you can see from the second error

> copy assignment operator of 'MyClass' is implicitly deleted because field 'dep_1' has a deleted copy assignment operator

Now, if you want to know why `dep_1` doesn't have a copy assignment operator, look at the third error:

> copy assignment operator of 'Dependancy' is implicitly deleted because field '_bar' has no copy assignment operator

It all boils down to `_bar` of type `Bar` not having a copy assignment operator, because it has been defined as `const`.

As you said, you can't change the class `Dependancy`, so the only solution is to make a copy assignment operator in `MyClass` yourself.

Comment: `_bar` has no copy assignment operator, not because it has been deleted, but because it is `const`.

Comment: Thanks for reply and thanks for being civilized. As @Quentin has mentioned, _bar does have a copy assignment.